# Feature Request: migration in off-topic close dialog

Tags: feature-request

When you vote to close on SO for being off topic, there is a migration dialog that appears. I feel one should be available here to migrate to SO (and potentially others, the extent of which I leave open for debate.) We had one just now that was a programming question. With how often, all across the internet, things are posted again and again in the wrong spot, I feel we're going to get a lot of use out of this feature.

For now, I simply flagged it, as I believe global moderators/employees have the ability to migrate at will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migration paths can be added after a site graduates from its beta stage.  There are only a few limited spots open for migration paths, so it needs to be proven that a significant number of questions for any suggested path are being asked.

In the meantime, you can comment on the question politely explaining and suggesting the question would be better served on another site.  Moderators do have the ability to migrate a question anywhere, so flagging for moderator attention is appropriate if there is no question the post belongs elsewhere.

Comment: I'll go along with that. :-) I do suspect that SO will end up being the primary place off topic questions would be sent to, although I do feel the pain of limited space. On SO, there's not enough room for all the potential places to send it. Oh, and when this goes public, it will likely be added to the list of "ones we wish we could easily migrate to" (i.e. without moderator intervention.) Anyway, thanks for your insight!